# How to use pipeline to load a trained and saved model

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

Recently, I have trained my own model using Transformers's Tranier module. And I saved these models. Now,I try to do some additional evaluation via pipeline module.But I meet some questions especially the following one which make me annoyed.

1. These is my code about training models

```py
train_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    seed=seed,
    num_train_epochs=args.epoch,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=args.batch,
    per_device_train_batch_size=args.batch,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=2000,
    save_strategy="epoch",
)

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer, padding=True)
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    train_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=tokenized_test_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=Compute_Metric,
)

trainer.train()
```

As we can see,this code will save a serises of checkpoints for me,but when I want to use `pipeline` to load these checkpoints,it told me I haven't not the file`pytorch_model.bin`. I checked the corresponding directory where I actually cannot find the file specified. All files of the checkpoint are shown below.

[image]

I can't understand why the `pytorch_model.bin` file doesn't appear when saving the model. I saw on some other websites that the files they saved using the same code all exist in this file.And I try to use other code

```py
trainer.save_model()
```

However the result is still the same. Does anyone know why this is? Or what should I do to let the pipeline read my model? Otherwise, Dose anyone could provide some papers of detecting AIGC text?

Does anyone know why this is? Or what should I do to let the pipeline read my model?